# Dropdown on click doing nothing

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am just starting JS, so this may be a stupid question. I want to make a dropdown, where if you pick one option the related paragraph would be visible. I didn't really know how to start this so I created the cars function to make the "e38value"  paragraph visible when clicking the e38 button,  but nothing happens when I click on it, and I have no clue why. If someone knows a better way doing this and it is not so complicated and a beginner could understand it I would be very happy if you could share it with me.

```js
var e38 = document.querySelectorAll('e38value')

function cars() {
  document.querySelectorAll('e38').onclick = function() {
    console.log('clicked');
    e38.classList.toggle("e38hidden");
  }
}
```

```css
.e38hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <menu>
    <menuitem id="kocsid">
    <a>Amilyen kocsid van</a>
    <menu>
      <menuitem id="Audi">
      <a>Audi</a>
      <menu>
        <menuitem><a>Audi</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a>Audi</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a>Audi</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a>Audi</a></menuitem>
      </menu>
      </menuitem>
      <menuitem id="BMW">
      <a>BMW</a>
      <menu>
        <menuitem><a class="e38">750 e38</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a>760 e65</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a>M3 e46</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a>M3 e62</a></menuitem>
      </menu>
      </menuitem>
      <menuitem id="Dodge">
      <a>Dodge</a>
      <menu>
        <menuitem onclick=""><a>Dodge</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a>Dodge</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a>Dodge</a></menuitem>
        <menuitem><a>Dodge</a></menuitem>
      </menu>
      </menuitem>
</nav>
<p id="e38value" class="e38hidden">e38 value</p>
```

Comment: Not only are you missing a period in front of your class selector, you should also know that `document.querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList and not a single element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are probably other better ways to acomplish that but here is how to fix you script:

```js
function cars() {
  document.querySelectorAll('.e38').forEach(function(e) {
    e.onclick = function(evt) {
      console.log('clicked', evt.target.innerHTML);
      document.getElementById("e38value").classList.toggle("e38hidden");
    }
  })
}

cars();
```

Note:

1. You need to call `cars()` to actually initialise the events.
2. The selector should be ".e38" which means all elements with the `e38` class
3. You need to call `forEach` as the querySelector returns an array of elements (in that case with only one element)
4. The click event can be used to locate the target (where it was clicked).

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b9728Lmk/1/

Does that solve the problem?

Comment: No, it still does not show up unfortunately.

Comment: @jayden if you open the fiddle and click on the element it should disappear.

Comment: I think we misunderstood each other. I When selecting the button, I want a paragraph to appear realated to the selected thing. So, for example when you click bmw -> e38 it shows a paragraph with some information about the car.

Comment: In that case, replace `evt.target.classList.toggle("e38hidden");` with `document.getElementById("e38value").classList.toggle("e38hidden");` -- is that what you expected?

Saved fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Lbajoqfc/

Comment: I encountered a problem.  I started adding more html elements(an hr also i tried an h2) and it suddenly stopped working,  I have no clue why. No error, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply define an `onchange` event which will remove the visibility of the previously selected item and make the currently selected item visible.

```js
function selectSection(value) {
    let context = document.getElementById("sections");
    for (let visible of context.querySelectorAll("p.visible")) {
        visible.classList.remove("visible");
    }
    if (context.children[value]) context.children[value].classList.add("visible");
}
```

```css
#sections > p:not(.visible) {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<select id="section-selector" onchange="selectSection(this.value)">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="0">First</option>
    <option value="1">Second</option>
    <option value="2">Third</option>
    <option value="3">Fourth</option>
    <option value="4">Fifth</option>
</select>

<div id="sections">
    <p>section 1</p>
    <p>section 2</p>
    <p>section 3</p>
    <p>section 4</p>
    <p>section 5</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is an updated version [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uda67nx4/)

```
var  menuItemToClick = document.querySelectorAll('.e38')


function cars(){
// I use for here because the menuItemToClick is an array that containt all element having class name e38
  for (var i = 0; i < menuItemToClick.length; i++) {
      menuItemToClick[i].addEventListener('click', function(event) {
          console.log('clicked');
          ParagraphToHide = document.querySelectorAll('#e38value');
          //I use [0] because the ParagraphToHide is an array, as we use an id we are pretty sure that we will select the first element 
          ParagraphToHide[0].classList.toggle("e38hidden");
      });
  }
} 

cars();
```

Comment: It still does not show up unfortunately. :/

Comment: I update my answer and I add the link of JsFiddle for you can test

Comment: Thanks, it works fine in  JSFiddle, but something is wrong with my code because it won't do anything for me.

Comment: I just changed the Javascript, can you check the console of your  browser and ensure that  the browser cache is cleared ?